# Association Help In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, associations, inner-join

I'm making a movie review application. A user can scroll through the different reviews that have been created and save them to a list. In my console, I'm unable to access the user's list reviews. User.list.reviews. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!!

Here are my current models and associations.

**User Model**

```
has_one :list
has_many reviews, :through => :list
```

**List Model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews
```

**Review Model**

```
has_many :lists
has_many :users, :through => :lists
```

**Schema: List**

```
user_id
review_id
```

Comment: Kindly simplify your question as what are you looking for..?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm trying to create a list in my application that includes reviews from my review model. Each user has one list, which can have multiple reviews. I'm stuck on how to make my associations.My list table is the joined table with review_id and user_id. Currently, when I try to access the reviews in a user's list I'm getting this error - o such column: reviews.list_id

Comment: Does that make more sense? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you should replace has_many :reviews on list model for has_and_belongs_to_many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema, a List has one user ID and one review ID. So a List can only ever have one of those things. But you want a User to have just one List, while the List has many Reviews.

It then gets more complex, because a List can have many Reviews. But since many different Users can put Reviews into their own lists, one Review might appear in several Lists. In short, List `has_and_belongs_to_many :reviews` and Review `has_and_belongs_to_many :lists`. This means you need somewhere to put the List ID and Review ID pair that express this relationship - it's called a *join table*. The convention is just concatenate the two names of the related two tables to get the name of the join table - so if we have tables `lists` and `reviews`, we need a join table called `lists_reviews` (you can override this but it's easier to just go with the convention).

A bare minimum Rails migration would be:

```
create_table :users do |t|
end

create_table :lists do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user # Leads to "user_id" column
end

create_table :reviews do |t|
end

create_table :lists_reviews do |t|
  t.belongs_to :list   # Leads to a "list_id" column
  t.belongs_to :review # Leads to a "review_id" column
end
```

Given this, and given that with `#has_one` you're supposed to put `#belongs_to` in the thing it has, too, so List should `belong_to :user`, we get:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base # Rails <= v4
  has_one  :list
  has_many :reviews, :through => :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
  has_many :users, :through => :lists
end
```

And with all this dumped into an empty Rails shell we can test it at the console:

```
u1 = User.new; u1.save!
u2 = User.new; u2.save!

l1 = List.new( user: u1 ); l1.save!
l2 = List.new( user: u2 ); l2.save!

r1 = Review.new; r1.save!
r2 = Review.new; r2.save!
r3 = Review.new; r3.save!

l1.reviews << r1
l1.reviews << r2
l1.save!

l2.reviews << r2
l2.reviews << r3
l2.save!

u1.list
# => #<List id: 1, user_id: 1>
u1.list.reviews
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: 1>, #<Review id: 2>]>
u2.list
# => #<List id: 2, user_id: 2>
u2.list.reviews

# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: 2>, #<Review id: 3>]>
l1.user
# => #<User id: 1>
l2.user
# => #<User id: 2>

r1.users
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1>]>
r1.lists
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<List id: 1, user_id: 1>]>
r2.users
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1>, #<User id: 2>]>
r2.lists
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<List id: 1, user_id: 1>, #<List id: 2, user_id: 2>]>
r3.users
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 2>]>
r3.lists
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<List id: 2, user_id: 2>]>
```

...it works.

Comment: One comment to follow up - the above also means you can change that `has_one` to a `has_many` and thus `has_many :reviews, :through => :lists`, noting the plural on `lists`. Now a user will have lists, instead of just one list. You wouldn't need to change your data, but you'd have `user.lists` instead of `user.list`. You'd do e.g. `user.list[0].reviews` instead of just `user.list.reviews`, and `user.reviews` would return a full collection of every Review across every List owned by the User. You may never want to allow multiple Lists for a User, but it's nice to know it'd be a simple change!

Comment: Thanks for all of this Andrew! Very helpful.

Comment: No worries, I find this kind of thing really useful revision when I've been away from Rails / more interesting associations for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Schema: List

```
user_id
review_id
```

This implies that your List belongs-to one user and also belongs-to one review... but you've defined your list associations like this:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews
```

So Rails is getting confused as to why a list has a review_id (which is a belongs_to association thing). and is looking at the Review model, hoping it will have a `list_id` column... because that's how you'd solve that one... and yet your Review model has many list, so it can't resolve the issue.

Can you tell us what you'd actually like to happen? How should these things be related? should we change the associations you've defined to match the id-columns or can you more completely specify the relationships between models (eg with an object diagram) and then we can tell you how to alter your id-columns/associations to match your object-diagram?

Comment: Ok the confusion part makes sense. I'm trying to let a user have a list that can have as many reviews in it as they want.

Comment: Also, a review can be in multiple user's list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` for this. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association.

The problem is that your List model has_many reviews, and your Review model has_many lists. If two models both have a has_many relation to each other, how can you model this in the database? That is, where would you put the foreign key? Whichever table has the foreign key can only have a belongs_to relation to the other table. i.e. it can only belong to *one* record on the other table.

The solution to this is to use a join table. In rails this will usually have a name of something like `lists_reviews`. This join table would have two foreign keys, one for the lists table, and one for reviews. This way, each table can have a has_many relation to the other. In rails, you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` to do this. Check out the link above for more.